# Generators of the conformal group in 1 dimension

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups, lie-algebras, conformal-geometry, conformal-field-theory

I was studying this book about the conformal group, and it explains the generators of the group in this way: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d5iq.jpg) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIZcL.jpg)

I don’t get why you can’t obtain the generators in d=1 following this reasoning. Everything there is also valid in d=1 except the L generator is zero. How to generalize this reasoning in d=1?

For example in this paper https://inspirehep.net/literature/108211 there are the generators in d=1.

The book is Conformal Field Theory by Philippe di Francesco.

SOLVED: The solution was explained later in the book for the case d=2 and the reasoning is the same as in the case d=1: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8jkP.jpg)

Comment: What do you not get? For $d=1$, there is no constraint on the function $f$, and so any smooth diffeomorphism is conformal. This is fairly obvious - a metric in one dimension is locally just a non-zero function, and acting on it by a diffeomorphism just transforms this to another non-zero function.

Comment: Look at this paper: https://inspirehep.net/literature/108211                      Here you have d=1 but there are the generators of the conformal group.

Comment: The point is for $d=1$ there are an _infinite_ number of generators, since the diffeomorphism group is infinite-dimensional (at least locally). In the paper you link to it seems the authors have chosen to concentrate on the $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$-subgroup of fractional linear transformations, and work out the generators of that. This is a 3-dimensional subgroup of the full (infinite-dimensional) diffeomorphism group of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don’t see the point of calling the Sl(2,R) algebra the algebra of the conformal group, though. Even if I agree with what you said. (Bottom of Pag 7 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.4403)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if d=1 the conformal map equation does not put any constraint on the scale factor f(x), any smooth and invertible map is conformal. When d=1, every generator vanishes except translation, CST, and dilation. One example of such a conformal theory is conformal quantum mechanics, symmetric under SL(2,R), see:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.05596

You don't have to generalize the reasoning in your book, as the discussion is perfectly valid when d=1. (You get three generators, one of which is the Hamiltonian of the system, the other two are just "t" times the preceding generator, you can check the commutators and confirm that this is indeed a SL(2,R) algebra)

Comment: I think you should be clear here: classically, there are an infinite number of generators. As you said, any smooth and invertible map is conformal, and so the conformal group is infinite dimensional. I don't know much about the quantum case, but I can imagine it is not possible to preserve the full conformal symmetry in the quantum theory (i.e. the theory has anomolies), but it is possible to preserve the 3-dimensional $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ subgroup of the conformal symmetries. However, Demuna seemed to be asking about the classical symmetry.